# ¿por que mi toolbar aparece debajo de los elementos de los fragments?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

Bueno el problema es el siguiente, tengo una toolbar  que en versiones de lolipop en adelante se muestra correctamente, pero en versiones de kit kat para abajo, la toolbar se pone por debajo de los elementos de mis fragments ya estuve investigando y aun no lo eh resuelto

aqui esta mi styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    -->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>


</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

</style>




<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

</style>
```

y mi app_bar_main.xml(caba aclarar que estoy usando un navegation_drawer )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

toolbar oculta un poco por las card view

[image: toolbar oculta]

[image: Y aquí ni siquiera se ve la toolbar y en versiones posteriores se ve perfectamente]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí ni siquiera se ve la toolbar y en versiones posteriores se ve perfectamente

Ojala me pudieran ayudar....

Gracias

Comment: La toolbar es para android 5 en adelante ..

Comment: @AshleyG. Con las "support library", se puede mostrar  le Toolbar en OS inferiores a 5.0.

Comment: @Jorgesys que interesante dato Jaja es que no hago una app para android  5 < hace mucho tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

En este caso puedes definir el `FrameLayout` debajo del `Toolbar` mediante la propiedad `android:layout_below`, realizalo de esta forma:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
```

De esta manera siempre se mostrará el contenido del `Fragment` abajo del `Toolbar`.

Comment: Gracias lo intente y aun asi , permanecio por debajo la toolbar

Comment: estas seguro que es el contenido del Fragment o es el contenido de lo que carga este include: <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

Comment: el content main conttiene este codigo `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="paquete.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    >

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`

Comment: creo que tenian un error en con  `tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"` pero aun asi corrigiendolo no se muestra, como deseo seguire buscando

Answer (score 0):

Quizás la solución podría ser agregar un LinearLayout con orientación vertical

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
    
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ya lo intente asi y no funciono